# What is an active bounty?

Tags: discussion

What is an active bounty?  Please explain.  I am a new Pi user and don't have a clue what is being asked of me.  What are your quality standards?

Answer (score 3):

Top right there is a "help" menu.  Under the "Help Center" option you will find:

[What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

This site is part of the Stack Exchange network, which has a very uniform interface/format.  This is our particular "meta" board (each site has one), for questions about this site in particular, but there is also a sort of [master Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for the whole network, which has [a `bounty` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) with ~1400 questions currently -- so a lot of information.

> What are your quality standards?

With questions, you are expected to have made some effort to research your problem first, and explain the effort you have made.  You are also expected to include relevant details and have paid attention to [the tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and the stuff under "Asking" in the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Beware that just because online help is free does not mean it is wise to regard it as infinite in supply and therefore infinitely disposable.  What is wise is to consider the perspective of the people you are asking for help, and to make it as simple and straightforward to provide you with an answer as possible.  I am fond of recommending the internet classic [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), which although a bit dated language wise (swap "hackers" for "people" and you will get the point) is an excellent introduction to how places like this evolved into their current form, why they are the way they are, and **what the mindset of the people who do much/most of the helping is.**

With regard to answers, posting a link with "Here is the answer" is frowned upon -- that's fine in a comment, which requires 10 rep (i.e., a few upvotes).