# How do I search for answers to my question?

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question but I have no idea how to find an answer to that question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41583/why-doesnt-pi-browse-the-internet-i-get-the-oops-comment). Answers will appear beneath the question and any comments. At the moment that question does not have any answers.

I mention comments because you have not replied to the comment that was posted. As stated without some additional info from you. your question is likely to be remain unanswered.

Also, if you have not already please read through the site tour and FAQ as described in your previous [question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/what-is-an-active-bounty).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Steve's answer, a word about how and where to find your original question again.

Click your identicon/avatar-icon in the top-bar of the page - the icon that sits next to the numbers reading your repuation and the badges you've earned. It's the area where your on-screen name will be shown when hovering the mouse over.

You'll be led to the **Activity** subpage of your profile. On the lefthand side you'll find links to all the questions you have asked.